# Moving a platform left to right with continuous movement

Tags: unity, c#, moving-platforms

I made a 2D game with Unity, and I am trying to create a platform that will move from left to right continuously, but I don't know how to make the platform move a greater distance then -1 to 1 units because I use the `Mathf.Sin` function. I can only control the speed of the platform.

Here is my code:

```
private Vector2 startPosition;
private int speed;

void Start () 
{
    startPosition = transform.position;
    speed = 3;
}

void Update() 
{
    transform.position = 
        new Vector2(startPosition.x + Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed), transform.position.y);
}
```

Here is what the code actually does:

[image: An animation of my moving platform]

How can I control the distance that the platform can move to each side? For now, it can only move 1 unit to each side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is, your code gives your platform a movement distance of 2 units; 1 unit in either direction of its starting position. To allow further movement, all you need to do is effectively *multiply* the current movement value.

```
/// <summary>The objects initial position.</summary>
private Vector2 startPosition;
/// <summary>The objects updated position for the next frame.</summary>
private Vector2 newPosition;

/// <summary>The speed at which the object moves.</summary>
[SerializeField] private int speed = 3;
/// <summary>The maximum distance the object may move in either y direction.</summary>
[SerializeField] private int maxDistance = 1;

void Start()
{
    startPosition = transform.position;
    newPosition = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    newPosition.x = startPosition.x + (maxDistance * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed));
    transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

By multiplying your movement algorithm of `Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed)` by a distance value of `maxDistance`, you effectivley tell your platform to allow movement of `maxDistance` units in either direction. The above example gives behavior identical to your current movement; 1 unit of distance in either direction, reversing its direction at `-1` and `1`. With `maxDistance = 50`, for example, the platform will move between `-50` and `50`.

Be aware that as `maxDistance` increases, you will likely want a lower `speed`. `speed` effectively controls how much time it takes to complete an entire movement arc, in this context, not the rate in which it moves in that arc. With `maxDistance = 1` and `speed = 3`, the platform moves between `-1` and `1` over 3 seconds. With `maxDistance = 10` and `speed = 3`, the platform moves between `-10` and `10` over 3 seconds. Due to the much greater distance, the platform will move *a lot* faster to cover the ground in the same amount of time. To give the same general speed, you would want something more like `maxDistance = 10` and `speed = 30`. *I would personally rename `speed` to `maxTime`, though I have not done so in the above example.*

I will address the semantic alterations I *have* made, to avoid confusion:

- The addition of `newPosition` gives you a local Vector2 to hold your derived "next position" co-ordinate. We can then work out the updated `newPosition.y` value on the fly, and do not have to worry about `newPosition.x` before passing it into `transform.position`, as this value should not change in the current context.
- Serializing `speed` and `maxDistance` with `[SerializeField]` serialises these values for the Unity Inspector. As a result, they have retained their `private` protection, but you can still change them on the fly from the Inspector.
- Initialising `speed` and `maxDistance` inline with the variable declaration simply prevents any Inspector-altered value from resetting when you hit play, and call `Start()`. You may wish to have these in `Start()`, just remember that these values will then override any values you have provided through the Inspector. For testing purposes, you can still change the values in the Inspector *during* a play-test to see the effects in-game.

As it stands, you also want to remember that this deliberately constrains movement to a specific value in either direction. That means that this would not work accurately if you wanted less symmetrical movement; for example, it would not work accurately if you wanted your platform to move `20` units to the left, but only allow `10` units of movement in the opposite direction. It could only be constrained to `+-10` or `+-20`. There are more advanced implementations you could look at to reach this sort of functionality, if needed, though they appear out of scope for the context of this question.